# In iOS,is there leak risk if I write the secret key in the code?

Tags: ios, secret-key

As the title say.If I write the secret key in the code,can the attacker get that?

Comment: yes, there is a risk.

Comment: So,how the attacker get the secret key?

Comment: Disassemble your code or scan through the binary looking for it. There are steps you can take to obfuscate the key and make it harder,  but if your app can get the key then in theory an attacker can too.  The trade off isnthe value of the information that is protected vs the effort required to get the key.